# Python's translate function begins to fail after many repetitions. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a program that finds the helicity of residues in a protein over time. I'm new to python and I've been having trouble with the translate function.

Protein trajectory files pretty big. The translate function works fine for about 50% of the file, but somewhere between 50% and 51% of the way through (maybe this is significant because it always happens in the same spot) it begins to break down.

Originally, one frame of time looks like this

```
['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C'
'C' 'C' 'C']
```

After my program runs, the first 50% looks like this

```
CHHHHCCCHHHHHHHHHH
CCC
```

After 50%, the translate begins to break down into this

```
C H H H C C C C H H H H C H H H H C
 C C C
```

It continues to break down until the end when it just looks like the original. I used the following loop to edit the file.

```
for i in range(numTrajs):
     traj = 'traj'
     traj += `i`
     traj += '.xtc'
     t = md.load(traj, top = fileName)
     structure = md.compute_dssp(t)
     line = str(structure).translate(None," []'")
     time.sleep(.1)
     fout.write(line)
     fout.flush()
```

The sleep function isn't necessary, I just added it in an attempt to give the computer "breathing room". I would try to give it a larger break, but these are very large files and giving it a full second might not be a viable option.

Is there any way to ensure that the translate function keeps working correctly no matter how long the file is? Thanks for the help!

Edit:

Here is what it looks like when the translate begins breaking

```
241508 CCCCCCCCCHHHCHHHHC
241509 CCC
241510 CCCCCCCCHHHCCHHHHC
241511 CCC
241512 CCCCCCCCHHHCCHHHHC
241513 CCC C C
241514  C C C H H H H C H H H H H H C C C C
241515   C C C
241516  C C C C C C C C H H H H C C H H H H
241517   C C C
241518  C C H H H H C C C C C C C H H H H H
241519   H H C
241520  C C C C H H H C H H H C C C H H H H
241521   C C C
241522  C C C H H H H C C H H H H H H H H H
241523   H H C
241524  C H H H H H C C H H H H H H H H H H
241525   H H C
241526  C C C C H H H C C C C C C H H H H C
241527   C C C
241528  C C H H H H C C H H H H H H H H H C
241529   C C C
241530  C H H H H C C C H H H H H H H H H H
```

It seems like translate() stops working in the middle of line 241513

Before translate using repr()

```
['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H'\n  'H' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H'\n  'H' 'H' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']\n ['C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C' 'C' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'C'\n  'C' 'C' 'C']]
```

After translate using repr()

```
   CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCHHHCCHHHHC\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCCCCCCHHHHH\nHHC\nCCCCCCCCCHHHCCCHHH\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCHHHCHHHHCC\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCCCCCCHHHHC\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCCCCCCHHHHC\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCCHHHCHHHHC\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCHHHCCHHHHC\nCCC\nCCCCCCCCHHHCCHHHHC\nCCC
```

After more investigation, I've come to the conclusion that it probably isn't the translate() function. After trying a solution with join(), I am still having the same problem around the 59% mark.

Comment: So you're using `str.translate` just to delete characters? If its behaviour is inconsistent you may have found a bug in the implementation, which should be reported to the developers - however, either way a reproducible example is required.

Comment: After your `structure = ` line, add `s = str(structure); print repr(s); line = s.translate(None, " []'"); print repr(line)`.  That way we can see exactly what's going on when things begin to change.

Comment: Right. I'm still getting used to immutable strings. Do you know of a better way to delete them? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=python2.7;dist=unstable Is is this right place to report the bug? Should I run this program on multiple trajectories to prove I can reproduce it and provide them with all of the files?

Comment: After adding those print statements, about half remove the spaces and apostrophes but the rest don't. It's hard to find any patterns though.

Comment: @Garett: edit your question to include the *exact* output from the first one which fails.

Comment: @Garrett: that isn't the output of a before-and-after `repr` (not merely a print).  In order to know whether it's translate or your data which is changing, we need to see exactly what it is.

Comment: @DSM: Is there a way to retain the end lines after using repr? As you can see there are 100,000s of lines. Trying to get halfway through that manually because it's all on the same line is hell.

Comment: @DSM: Actually looking at the repr output, it looks like the translate function never stops working. I'll post the last few lines of the before and after.

Comment: Try to create a file containing a few lines before the first failure and after the first failure. So it will be easier and faster to debug and analyze.

Comment: @stenci: From the "print repr" or the file I've been writing to? The repr doesn't ever fail so I posted the last few lines. I tried to write to a file using write(repr(line)) to see if the problem was write(), but that wasn't it.

Comment: I meant try to reduce the size of the input data set, to see if the problem is on the file size or on the data. For example try to create a new file containing only the lines from 241500 to 241520 and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Done. It worked fine when I used fewer data.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain your string much simpler. You frame is a list of string, so just use .join method, like this: `line="".join(structure)`.

**Update**

As discussed in comments, `structure` is in fact a numpy 2d array, the proper way to write it to the human readable file it iterate over its axis in proper order and write chunks to file. See short example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']])
```

if you call str method you obtain a string representation, which is supposed to us as is, like:

```
>>> print(str(x))
[['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
 ['E' 'F' 'G' 'H']]
```

Since you want to write custom representation, use iteration over array. It may be slower, but you has more control over result:

```
>>> for row in x:                                             
>>>    line_str = "".join(str(element) for element in row)
>>>    print(line_str)
ABCD
EFGH
```

For you case replace print(line_str) with fout.write(line_str). Also, most probably, you don't need to call four.flush() after each row.

Comment: This won't remove the apostrophes or brackets will it? I'm trying to remove brackets, apostrophes, and white space because their are some irregularities in the way it's printed. Removing these make the data much easier to analyze.

Comment: Oh sorry I misinterpret what is a structure object. 

 So:`str(structure)` converts it to string and there is possible other way to convert it, so please tell if you use some library to obtain it or what type is it.

Other option is to use `line="".join(x for x in str(structure) if x not in set([" ","\", "\n", "\"']))`

Comment: Hmm googled it, https://github.com/mdtraj/mdtraj/blob/master/mdtraj/geometry/dssp.py

so you obtain a 2d numpy array, I would advice you to reshape it manually into 1d array/list and join them later. Otherwise you should study numpy source for __str__ method implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your method worked for longer than mine, but it still can't make it the entire way through the file. It starts to break down after about 59%. There must be something deeper to this.

Comment: You're right, this format is a lot better! Unfortunately the original problem still exists.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because mentioned approach doesn't use translate function at all.  Please show your updated code.

Comment: Right, I realized that the problem wasn't the translate function like I thought it was. When using open() I used the 'r+' descriptor. After rearranging my code I replaced 'r+' with 'w' and the code began to work. I'm not sure why. Thanks for your help either way.